# Can you start with Pikachu in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've heard you can start with pikachu in pokemon go instead of the 3 standard starters. How would one do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

After digging deeper it seems you can in fact start with pikachu in Pokémon Go.

[Reddit post "You can get pikachu as your starter pokémon"](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rngo7/you_can_get_pikachu_as_your_starter_pokemon/)

> You need to walk away from the three starters in the beginning of the game, just like in the animé. After you walk away from them 4? Times, Pikachu will show up.

[image: screenshot of Reddit post confirming this]

[image: another Reddit post confirming this]

[pop news article agreeing that walking away gets you pikachu](http://www.thecountrycaller.com/39715-how-to-get-pikachu-as-starter-pokemon-in-pokemon-go/)

Comment: That's sneaky...

Comment: Is that the only way to get Pikachu?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee you can find them in the wild as well

Comment: Is the Pikachu any more powerful than the other 3 starters? I got a Charmander with 12 CP. How many CP does the starter Pikachu have? Not that it really matters, your not going to battle with a 10-12 CP anyway...

Comment: Too late to read it now anyway +1

Comment: "just like in the anime" this did not happen in the anime

Comment: @Pyritie tell the guy on reddit not me.

Comment: @Chris I got Pikachu as a starter and he had 10 CP (and still has), so, no, not really more powerful than the other 3 starters.

Answer (score 4):

You can! Walk away from the original starters four or five times and then a Pikachu will show up along with them (though not on its own as I originally thought, so be on the lookout)!

Happy hunting!