# Can't find the main menu in Pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

A web search says to find the ball at the bottom of the screen and tap it and that opens the main menu. But there is no ball at the bottom of the screen:

[image: Pokemon go screen]

If I could get to the main menu, I could turn off sound, etc. (No, the thing in the lower left corner is not a menu.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you've just installed the game because there are three starter Pokemon around you. Before you can access the rest of the game, you must choose to catch one of the three Pokemon.

As you can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/S1haN8xvYz4?t=260), capturing one of the starter Pokemon is an unavoidable part of the tutorial.

Comment: Note that if you walk away from the starter Pokemon 4 times, [Pikachu will  appear as a catchable starter Pokemon](https://www.gamesradar.com/pokemon-go-has-a-secret-pikachu-starter-hiding-in-its-tutorial/). There's nothing special about it though, it's just a little Easter egg.

Comment: Pretty fun easter egg indeed, although probably not many people encountered it. Also talked about here on SO: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272840/80141

Comment: Imagine that, basic controls not available yet until you fly the airplane for a while.. but you need to check the airplane manual, which is probably locked inside the basic controls. Well I guess this is no place for old Mr. me.

Comment: Well, there is a single instruction "catch a pokemon" near the top, and there are three interesting creatures nearby.  To me, the game's central theme is exploration which includes the game's own mechanics.  If that seems uninteresting, you will probably not enjoy the game.